# How to compare effectively two SHA512Managed hash values

Tags: c#, string, hash, sha512

I use SHA512Managed class for coding user password string. I initually create etalon string coded in the folowing way:

1. Convert password string (for example "Johnson_#1") to byte array;
2. Get hash value of this byte array using SHA512Managed.ComputeHash
   method. As you know, hash value gotten from SHA512Managed.ComputeHash(byte[])
   method is byte array too.

Then (in program loop) I convert this hash byte array to string in the following way:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < passwordСache.Length; i++)
{
    sBuilder.Append(passwordСache[i].ToString("x2"));
}
string passwordCacheString = sBuilder.ToString();
```

where the passwordСache is hash byte array and passwordCacheString is result string.

Finally, I store result string in MS SQL Server database table as etalon string.

The matter is in the folowing: If I periodically call SHA512Managed.ComputeHash(byte[]) method and each time pass to it the same byte array as input parameter (for example obtained from "Johnson_#1" string), then the content of returned hash byte array will differs from time to time.

So, if I convert such hash byte array to string (as I showed above) and compare this string to etalon string that is in database table, then the content of this string will differ from content of etalon string though the same string ("Johnson_#1") underlies.

Better defined the question

My question is: **Is there a way of determining that two compared SHA512Managed hash byte arrays with different content were created on the base of the same string?** Yuor help will be appreciated highly.

Comment: *then the content of returned hash byte array will differs from time to time*: **this is absolutely impossible**. An hash function is deterministic. Same input --> same output. You are doing an error somewhere else. Classical error is in the way you convert the `string` to `byte[]`.

Comment: So the result SHA512Managed hash byte[] can't vary its content from time to time if the same string underlies?

Comment: It would be **totally** useless otherwise.

Comment: See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function): *A hash procedure must be deterministic—meaning that for a given input value it must always generate the same hash value. In other words, it must be a function of the data to be hashed, in the mathematical sense of the term. This requirement excludes hash functions that depend on external variable parameters, such as pseudo-random number generators or the time of day...*

Comment: No, the error is in the code that converts the `string` --> `byte[]`, because even `Convert.ToBase64String` is deterministic.

Comment: So I must have etalon SHA512Managed hash byte[] in database table and compare it with the SHA512Managed hash byte[] each time created on the base of the same password string?

Comment: You might want to read [HMACSHA512 versus Rfc2898DeriveBytes for password hash](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35250/hmacsha512-versus-rfc2898derivebytes-for-password-hash) before going too much further. Although its talking about using HMAC, many similar things can be said for plain SHA512 - yes, it's a cryptographic hash, but no, it's the wrong *sort* of hash to use for password hashing. I'd strongly advise just using a library function rather than rolling your own crypto if you're not aware of what you should use and when.

Answer (score -1):

As xanatos mentioned in his comments, hash functions must be deterministic. 
That is for the same input, you'll get the same hash output.

Try it for yourself:

```
            SHA512Managed sha512Managed = new SHA512Managed();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                var input = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                byte[] data = sha512Managed.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
                byte[] data2 = sha512Managed.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

                if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data) != Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data2)) {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Hash functions as we know them are useless");
                }
            }
```

Comment: I've tryed it. There has been no exception thrown. Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data) and Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data2) are equal.

Comment: Encoding.UTF8.GetString will not deliver a meaningful result on random data.

Comment: So, how can I get a meaningful result. What should I use to get it?

Comment: If I get SHA512 hash based on "Lulu" string - 'first hash', and save it somewhere, and then turn off-turn on my computer and again get SHA512 hash from "Lulu" - 'second hash', then 'first hash' will be equal to 'second hash' or will not?